# call may violate context's modifies clause

Tags: dafny

I'm writing a dafny code to verify a function, which change the head and tail of a queue, the function itself is verified but when I add main function, I get error: call may violate context's modifies clause, I don't have any new in my method, so there is no need to write ensures fresh. I don't know what the problem is, could anyone help me.

```
    class Quack<Data>
    {
        var buf: array<Data>;
        var m: int, n: int;

        ghost var shadow: seq<Data>;

        predicate Valid() reads this, this.buf
        { buf!=null && buf.Length!=0 && 0<=m<=n<=buf.Length && shadow==buf[m..n] }
    ...
        method HeadTail() modifies this, this.buf
    requires Valid()
    ensures Valid()
    ensures buf.Length == old(buf.Length)
    ensures |shadow| == |old(shadow)|
    ensures n == old(n) && m == old(m)
    ensures if n-m > 1 then (shadow[0] == buf[m] == old(buf[n-1])) && (shadow[|shadow| - 1] == buf[n-1] == old(buf[m]))
                            && shadow[1..|shadow| - 1] == old(shadow[1..|shadow| - 1])
                            && forall i:: (0 <= i < buf.Length && i != m && i != n-1) ==> (buf[i] == old(buf[i]))
            else buf == old(buf) && shadow == old(shadow)
    { 
        if(n-m > 1){
            buf[n-1], buf[m] := buf[m], buf[n-1];
            shadow := [buf[m]] + shadow[1..|shadow| - 1] + [buf[n - 1]];
        }
    }
}

        method Main()
        {   var q:= new Quack<char>(10);
            var l: char;
            q.Push('r'); q.Push('s'); q.Push('k'); q.Push('o'); q.Push('w');
            l:= q.Pop(); assert l=='w'; print l;  
            q.HeadTail();
            l:= q.Qop(); assert l=='o'; print l;
            l:= q.Pop(); assert l=='r'; print l;
            q.HeadTail();
            l:= q.Qop(); assert l=='k'; print l;    
            q.HeadTail();
            l:= q.Qop(); assert l=='s'; print l;        
            var e: bool:= q.Empty();
            if e {print "\nqueue empty\n";} else {print "\nqueue not empty\n";}
        }
```

The error happened at the second and thord time I call q.HeadTail() in main;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny will only modify arrays that have been ensured fresh, which means it allocated the array itself - remember `buf` is just a pointer! You must include `ensures buf == old(buf)` in `HeadTail` to tell Dafny that `buf` is still fresh (this way, the assertion is carried over from using `ensures fresh(buf)` in some previous method).

As you can see, `HeadTail` doesn't fail the first time it's called due to `fresh(buf)` having been asserted previously, however straight after this knowledge is lost - causing the second call of `HeadTail` to violate the modifies clause.

Comment: Thanks, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Method `HeadTail()` says it modifies `this` and `this.buf`. Method `Main` calls `HeadTail` on `q`, so that means the call modifies `q` and `q.buf`. Method `Main` does a `new` to obtain `q`, so `Main` is allowed to modify `q`. But there is no information about what `q.buf` is. To modify `q.buf`, `Main` must prove that `q.buf` is newly allocated (that is, allocated since the start of `Main`; in other words, `q.buf` must be fresh to `Main`).

I can't see your specifications of the constructor and `Push`, but I suspect you need to say `fresh(buf)` in the postcondition of the constructor. Then, as a postcondition of `Push`, you could write

```
ensures buf == old(buf) || fresh(buf)
```

However, if your `Quack` class never changes `buf` (I can't tell if it does or not), then it would be simpler to declare `buf` to be immutable:

```
const buf: array<Data>
```

Rustan